How to add css and bootstrap in python django
When I try to load css file along with bootstrap, my css file doesn't work but bootstrap works fine. I don't know what went wrong and it annoys me the fact that something that supposed to take minutes to work takes me days to make it work for me
enter image description here
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bs-brain@2.0.4/tutorials/buttons/button-1/assets/css/button-1.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>




try using this as your path ./css/style.css

also if you inspect element in your browser it should show you an error if the path to your css is incorrect

Yeah, devtools, network pane.  Set to css only.  You’d have found a 404, likely along with full url used.  Now copy that url and paste play around with modifying it, in the browser, till the css comes back.  then adjust href as per answer. The only django specific hassle is checking that your django {static/staticfiles} do work somewhere.  Frustrating but chalk it up to learning a new tool.

I found the solution
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "static/css/style.css">


I set up a basic example with this HTML in one folder, and a minimal style.css file in a css folder at the same level. Ultimately, I had to change the href for your stylesheet as follows
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "../css/style.css">

The trick was to change href to a relative path using ../

Like static images I would serve a custom css-file as static Django file in the static directory of the corresponding Django app and include it within the template using the static tag.
This will probably also make things easier if you want to go live later on.
